# How do I set the value of element in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

Why can't I do this in Angular.js:

```
document.getElementById('divid').value = 'Change Text to This';
```

And what is the "right" (Angular) way of doing it?

Comment: This should be a good place to start: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind

Comment: [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/547020)

Comment: http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Angular you use the `ng-model` directive in order to create a two-way data binding between your model (i.e. a JS variable) and the view (i.e. the `<div>`). Basically, this means that whenever you change the data in the view (through an input, for instance), the change will be reflected in your JS variable. See below:

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div>{{myVariable}}</div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="myVariable" />
    </div>
</html>
```

JS:

```
/* App global module */
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

/* Define controller to process data from your view */
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

   $scope.myVariable = "initialValue"; // this is the variable that corresponds to text inserted in your input

});
```

Here, myVariable will have "initialValue" as an initial value. Any further changes to the input will overwrite the value of this variable.

Also notice that `{{myVariable}}` injects the variable the data into your div. When you change the value in the input, the div text will be changed as well.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to bind a controller to your mark up and initialise your Angular app.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div id="divid" ng-controller="valueController">{{value}}</div>
</div>
```

Then you can simply define a scope variable in your controller

```
myApp.controller("valueController", function($scope) {
    $scope.value = "Hi!";
});
```

It is considered best to use the ng-app directive in the HTML tag of the page

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/M6MML/)