# click event on morris bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

I implement morris graph and also working on click function but i want when i clicked on bar then data of that bar will alert.so how can get data.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Morris.js Bar Chart Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="bar-example"></div>
    </body>
        <script>
    Morris.Bar({
      element: 'bar-example',
      data: [
        { y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
        { y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },
        { y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },
        { y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },
        { y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },
        { y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
        { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
      ],
      xkey: 'y',
      ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
      labels: ['Series A', 'Series B']
    });

    $( "#bar-example svg rect" ).on('click', function(data) {
      alert( data);//show [object.Object] when alert popup
    });
    </script>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 4):

First, thank you to let me discover [this cool graph library](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/). ;)

**This is an EDIT**
*After a couple tries...*
I ended up in a real simplification of my solution.
So for clarity, I removed all previous edit. You can see them in edit history anyway. ;).

So now, based on this [new example provided](http://jsbin.com/cenehediyi/edit?html,js,output) in comments below:

We are getting the needed infos in the summary below the graph:

```
var thisDate,thisData;
$( "#bar-example svg rect" ).on('click', function() {
    // Find data and date in the actual morris diply below the graph.
    thisDate = $(".morris-hover-row-label").html();
    thisDataHtml = $(".morris-hover-point").html().split(":");
    thisData = thisDataHtml[1].trim();

    // alert !!
    alert( "Data: "+thisData+"\nDate: "+thisDate );
});
```

`thisDate` and `thisData` hold nothing (empty) onload.
But they hold the last clicked bar values on click.
These variables are usable in other subsequent scripts, since declared outside of the `click()` handler.

See in [this **new CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/rLAyLb?editors=1011)

Comment: Ok... This is a bit more complex... Will try to find something.

Comment: Ok i'm wait @Louys Patrice

Comment: your answer is working but when graph resize it's return  unvalid info..see this link .http://jsbin.com/cenehediyi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: ok, I see. Not all dates are displayed in this case. I will try something else based on this last example. Hold on!

Comment: Haha... I just saw the light! This edit is really simplified.

Comment: I edited again so that you can use the values in other subsequent scripts.

Comment: Thanks you  @Louys Patrice.. How can we implement this graph in angular js 1?

Comment: I'm not used to Angular yet... Sorry.

Comment: Ok..Thanks  you :)

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25080124/2159528) could help you. Since you have the data contained in javascript variables... You can use them to set Angular variables. But about retreiving the bar values on click... I think my answer is complete. ;)

Comment: How can xaxis and yaxis set with label like i want to info user  that xaixs is date and unit is on yaxis..so how can i do this @ Louys patrice

Comment: I think you should start another SO question starting at where you are right now. The initial question was **«How can get data when I click on a bar to alert it?»** And I answered to that. Plz, accept this answer... And restart a clear question about the axis labels and Angular integration. The question will then pop in the newest and draw more attention. ;) I would have answered to these additionnal questions if I could, but you need more people on the case.

Comment: @louys from $( "#bar-example svg rect" ) i removed the svg rect and still it works

Answer (score 0):

I am not very proud of the following javascript function, but to retrieve the index of the rectangle on which we just click, I use it successfully.
Then I call a C# method to retrieve the values.

```
$('#m_Top10Applications svg rect').on('click', function (event) {  window.location.replace("MyPage.aspx?Top10Index=" + GetMorrisBarClickedBarIndex($this));});

function GetMorrisBarClickedBarIndex(par$ThisRect)
{
   var xRect = par$ThisRect[0].x.baseVal.value;
   var TheParent = par$ThisRect.parent();
   var Rectangles = TheParent.find("rect");
   var Rect0 = Rectangles[0];
   var Rect1 = Rectangles[1];
   var X0 = Rect0.x.baseVal.value;
   var X1 = Rect1.x.baseVal.value;
   var RectWidth = X1 - X0;
   var xPos = xRect - X0;
   var Index = Math.floor(xPos / RectWidth, 0);
   return Index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "rect" element is not in my line graph, so I just removed it. Thanks so much for this, it gave me exactly what I needed.

```
    var thisDate,thisData;
    $( "#morrisLine svg" ).on('click', function() {
        // Find data and date in the actual morris diply below the graph.
        thisDate = $(".morris-hover-row-label").html();
        thisDataHtml = $(".morris-hover-point").html().split(":");
        thisData = thisDataHtml[1].trim();

        // alert !!
        alert( "Data: "+thisData+"\nDate: "+thisDate );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Above examples were of line chart rather than bar charts with multiple bars of different colors.

Based on above solution below is my code in case you have three bars in your morris chart:

```
$('#bar-sixmonthstats svg rect').on('click', function () {
    _$month = $('.morris-hover-row-label').text();

    //debugger;
    barColor = $(this).attr('fill');
    var barType = '';

    switch (barColor) {
        case '#64a900': barType = 'PO'; break;
        case '#7acc00': barType = 'SO'; break;
        case '#4d8000': barType = 'WO'; break;
    }
                        
    console.log("Order Type : " + barType + "\nDate : " + _$month);
});
```